# AWS: is there any custom rules to check if an EC2 Instance is running on an old instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any custom rules to check if an EC2 Instance is running on an old instance type?

I know I can simply check the instance type by clicking on an EC2 instance, but what if I have bunch of EC2 instances? Click EC2 instances one by one will be inefficient. So I'd like to know is there any way I can setup custom rules to do it for me?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom bash or power shell script to find the list of instances and instance types. you can integrate the below command with your script and find the exact information.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

you can also use python boto3 to write a script.